# Wordpress category permalink pagination returns error 404

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, permalinks

I am facing an issue with category permalinks.
I have set post permalinks to custom structure which is

```
/%category%/blog/%postname%/
```

and this part is working fine.

Categories are served like this:
`/%category%/blog/` and they also work ok but only the first page. When I go to the next page `/%category%/blog/page/2/` link returns 404 error, because it is trying to find a post with such a title.

This wordpress site is a blog for the main site.
Main site is using nginx as a web server and apache is used for this WordPress blog.
There is a rewrite rule somewhere (I have no access to it and seems like guys in the company do not know where exactly is the code located) which rewrites **"site.com/blog/category"** into **"site.com/category/blog"** and this rewrite rule is not located in htaccess or in the theme - probably somewhere on the upper level. I have no access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `settings` > `Permalinks`

Under `Common Settings` set the permalink type to `plain` then test your links.

Once it is working change it back to your `custom` or `post name`

Comment: When I do this I get 404 for all the category links.

Comment: you get `404` with plain permalinks?

Comment: yes, but for category pages. If I open a link site.com/inspiration/blog/ I am getting 404 error.